# What is the onCreate command to launch a layout in the main .java file that contains two fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, oncreate

I have an .xml layout that consists of a fragment (on the left of the screen), and a container that is able to be filled with different fragments (on the right of the screen). When my app starts up I want the left fragment to appear and I want the container on the right side of the screen to be filled with one of the other fragments I have created [The example of what I want is in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wISMo.png)

[image]

I know there is something wrong with my main java file, but I can not figure out what. My app just keeps crashing on startup, even though my gradle builds.

Here is my code for main.xml that calls the fragment (menu fragment) and container (I do not have a java file for this layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/menuFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    class="it.anddev.bradipao.janus.MenuFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fr_menu">
</fragment>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/menuFragment"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menuFragment"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/menuFragment"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/menuFragment" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my java code that is my launcher activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;



// main activity (FragmentActivity provides fragment compatibility pre-HC)
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

// called when the activity is first created
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

if (savedInstanceState == null) {
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .add(R.id.menuFragment, new MenuFragment()).commit();
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are trying to add a fragment on the FrameLayout then use its id instead of fragment id.

Try below :

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         .add(R.id.container, new MenuFragment()).commit();
}
```

Comment: I have tried making this change, but my app still crashes on startup